# Face ,Eye and Mouth detection using haar-cascades

Tags: c#, image, face

I have detect eyes and mouth from the face, .. However, mouth is not detected properly
i apply this code on 3 picture but it doen't detect mouth accurately
u can see the pictures  here  [see the sample pictures here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYhWN.png) 
For fig1  it detect accurate  but for fig 2 and fig3 its doen't detect accurate

```
private void ProcessFrame(object sender, EventArgs arg)
{
    Image InputImg = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Emgu\a.jpg");
    Image<Bgr, byte> ImageFrame = new Image<Bgr, byte>(new Bitmap(InputImg));

    if (ImageFrame != null)   // confirm that image is valid 10             
    {
        Image<Gray, byte> grayframe = ImageFrame.Convert<Gray, byte>();
        var faces = grayframe.DetectHaarCascade(haarCascade, 1.4, 4,
                     HAAR_DETECTION_TYPE.DO_CANNY_PRUNING,
                      new Size(40, 40))[0];
        var nos = grayframe.DetectHaarCascade(nose);
        var eyes = grayframe.DetectHaarCascade(eye, 1.1, 1,
                  HAAR_DETECTION_TYPE.DO_CANNY_PRUNING,
                   new Size(20, 20));

       foreach (var eye2 in eyes[0])
       {
           Rectangle eyeRect1 = eye2.rect;
           ImageFrame.Draw(eyeRect1, new Bgr(Color.Pink), 2);
       }

       foreach (var noses1 in nos[0])
       {
          Rectangle noserect = noses1.rect;
          ImageFrame.Draw(noserect, new Bgr(Color.Blue), 2);
       }

        foreach (var face in faces)
        {
            ImageFrame.Draw(face.rect, new Bgr(Color.Green), 3);
            grayframe.ROI = face.rect;
            var mouths = grayframe.DetectHaarCascade(mouth, 
                      1.5, 10, 
                      Emgu.CV.CvEnum.HAAR_DETECTION_TYPE.DO_CANNY_PRUNING, 
                      new Size(20, 20));
            grayframe.ROI = Rectangle.Empty;

            foreach (var mouthsnap in mouths[0])
            {
                Rectangle mouthRect = mouthsnap.rect;
                mouthRect.Offset(face.rect.X, face.rect.Y);
                ImageFrame.Draw(mouthRect, new Bgr(Color.Red), 2);
            }
        }
    }
    CamImageBox.Image = ImageFrame;
}
```

Comment: Please read [ask], and try to cleanup the question some.  As it stands, it's very difficult to understand what singular specific problem you're experiencing.

Comment: sorry for my english

Comment: just see the picture nd u understand easily

Comment: use the debugger and see if you can `easily` pinpoint your issues and or problem

Comment: its simple question i cannot detect mouth accurately

Answer (score 0):

This is a data-driven error, not a code error: You need to also **train on faces with beards** to avoid this misclassification.

Your training set as shown (three images on the right) has no beards. In those images your Haar cascade learns that the dark curved line is a mouth.

It then thinks the beard in fig1 (image on the left) is also a mouth, because it is a large dark curved line. It has correctly drawn a box around that line, the "mouth" (actually a beard).

In general, increase the amount of training data to improve detection.

If this is *not* a data-driven problem, then look at approaches already posted in a related question ( [Eye and Mouth detection from face using haar-cascades](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14294627/eye-and-mouth-detection-from-face-using-haar-cascades?rq=1) ):

1. search for the mouth within the face box
2. dividing the face box into a top and bottom region, then searching within the bottom region.

Comment: thnks for reply
but in fig 1 u see there is a extra pink box on mouth why ?
i am using pink rectangle on detected eyes but it also appear in mouth too