# how to decide face feature after detecting face and mouth using emgucv

Tags: c#, emgucv

I am working on emotion detection in c#, for that by using emgucv and haarcascades xml i detected face mouth and eyes, now how to decide that what is the emotion on the face for detection i am using this code

```
var faces = grayframe.DetectHaarCascade(
                        haar, 1.4, 4,
                        HAAR_DETECTION_TYPE.DO_CANNY_PRUNING,
                        new Size(nextFrame.Width / 8, nextFrame.Height / 8)
                        )[0];
  foreach (var f in faces)
  {    
  image.Draw(f.rect, new Bgr(Color.Blue), 2);    
    gray.ROI = f.rect;
 var mouthsDetected = gray.DetectHaarCascade(mouth, 
                          1.1, 10, 
                          Emgu.CV.CvEnum.HAAR_DETECTION_TYPE.DO_CANNY_PRUNING, 
                          new Size(20, 20));
 gray.ROI = Rectangle.Empty;


 foreach (var m in mouthsDetected [0])
 {
      Rectangle mouthRect = m.rect;
      mouthRect.Offset(f.rect.X, f.rect.Y);
      image.Draw(mouthRect , new Bgr(Color.Red), 2);
 }
```

}

i found this code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14294627/eye-and-mouth-detection-from-face-using-haar-cascades). Can anyone suggest that what should i have to do to find feature of faces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The easy solution is pre-trained classifier "smile detector".

   String smile_cascade_name = "haarcascades\haarcascade_smile.xml";

   I don't remember if "haarcascade_smile.xml" come with Emgu. If not, it probably come with opencv source code. https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/master/data/haarcascades
2. The hard one is train it yourself. This is pretty involving. You can go to ImageNet download all the smile picture, sad picture and other emotion, then train it with opencv's build-in "opencv_traincascade" function.http://coding-robin.de/2013/07/22/train-your-own-opencv-haar-classifier.html. Sometimes it spends me 2 weeks to train one classifier.

You can use the xml trained with opencv in EMGU code.